# How to write jqPlot values into variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, canvas, jqplot

I use jqPlot to plot a line chart out of a .csv-file.
I need to get the xmax and ymax values of the plot and use them for further processings.

How do I get this or any other values and write them inside my own variables?

**EDIT**

Let's say this is my plot:
[image]

What I need is not the maximum x-value from the array (here 1380). I need to get the maximum value from the plot (here 2000). For further processing I would like to add rectangles inside the plot, see second picture: and calculate their height as a x-value and not as their pixel-value.

[image]

Therefore I need to access the jqplot variables, not the array variables I give over to jqplot.

Comment: Can u post a jsfiddle.net demo of the chart and indicate which values you want to retreive?

Comment: You might want to add some code for how you are processing your csv file and populating your chart before you offer a bounty. Your question probably didn't get enough attention because you didn't add enough detail for anybody to help you.

Comment: In general, you have an array of values, so just loop through the array keeping track of the largest value you've found.

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter: http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/qX4LS/1/
I need to retrieve the "10" as the xmax value and the 10.0 as the ymax value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, at some point you have an array of values that you passed to jqPlot to draw the graph, for example:

```
var myData = [[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]];
```

If you want to find the maximum x and y values, you just need to loop through the array keeping track of the largest value you've found so far.

```
var maxX, maxY;
for (var i=0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    if (myData[i][0] > maxX || !maxX) {
        maxX = myData[i][0];
    }
    if (myData[i][1] > maxY || !maxY) {
        maxY = myData[i][1];
    }
}
```

Here's a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LAbvj/

EDIT: Ok, so I think what you are now asking for is the maximum for each axis. In that case, this is simple:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [
    [3, 7, 19, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5]
]);
console.log(plot1.axes.xaxis.max);
console.log(plot1.axes.yaxis.max);
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KJTRF/

Comment: I appreciate your response. Please view my edited question for further information.

Comment: @gco: Ok, so I *think* what you are asking for is the maximum values on each axis (not the maximum of your data). In that case, see my edit.

Comment: awesome! Thanks. The bounty can and will be awarded in 20 hours ;)